# Oracle Service Bus: writing binary file to a new directory

Tags: integration, osb

We have http-based reporting service producing pdf/rtf/xls etc reports. We need to put the results to directories based on report parameters.

Namely call http://company.com/reportService?customer=Joe and store the result into /rootDirectory/Joe

Is it possible with OSB at all? Other transports like (s)ftp?

Answer (score 0):

you could parse the file to Base64 and send to other service to save the file. Or if you are using bpel there is a FTP adapter there.